# Jenkins cloud config save always throws 504

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, cicd

Team,

I have 20-30 pod templates under jenkins cloud config. Whenever I save anything it takes like 20-35seconds and finally it lands into 504 error or no valid crumb error. I have to then go to the top level home page and get back to cloud config. However the changes I make are saved. but what could be the reason for this? even on other job/folders when I save a jenkinsfile, server sometimes take very long time and in some big jenkinsfiles it throws same 504 error. but changes do get saved. not sure what is the reason. do I need to reduce the pod templates to podSpecs within jenkinsfiles?

Comment: Is your server behind a reverse proxy?